# Как сохранить данные ArrayList в Adndroid при повороте экрана?

Tags: android

Имеется класс-шаблон `OwnClass`.
В `MainActivity` есть объект этого класса `ArrayList`.
Как сохранить `view` с помощью `onSaveInstanceState`?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList("list", (ArrayList<>) output1);
    }

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        output1 = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("list");
        lv.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter<OwnClass>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output1)));
    }
```

Вылетает ошибка,что ожидается `String` а найден `OwnClass`. И это понятно,так как используется метод `getStringArrayList()`.

Если `OwnClass implements Parcelable`
а потом `outState.putParcelableArrayList(arrayList);`
При повороте экрана возвращает в каждом в значении при каждом индексе `com.example.user.parforme.OwnClass51123452`. Хеш конечно разный у всех.
Но как возобновить правильно?

Comment: Что из себя представляет `OwnClass`? Он наследуется от `View`?

Answer (score 10):

В лекции Дмитрия Калиты (вторая лекция курса) на [он-лайн курсах e-legion](http://learndroid.e-legion.ru/) разработчиков андроид при участии Google, озвучен такой способ сохранения объектов, которые не упаковываются в `Bundle` - создается фрагмент, который не имеет UI-интерфейса, он объявляется `setRetainInstance(true)` - то есть защищен от уничтожения при пересоздании активити.
В этом фрагменте реализуется метод-геттер для хранения сущности абсолютно любого типа, например, объекта-модели. При переходе активити в состояния изменения конфигурации в этот фрагмент сохраняется любая сущность, затем, после того, как конфигурация изменилась из фрагмента, с помощью метода-геттера, извлекается сохраненная сущность.
Способ, лично для меня немного необычный и похож на хак, но он реально удобнее сериализации и парцебилизации объектов.

Краткие наброски кода, за подробностями прошу на лекции, там еще много чего интересного узнать можно.

**UPDATE CODE** - мне кажется так лучше, чем первый вариант.

**SaveFragment**

```
public class SaveFragment extends Fragment {
    private  Model mModel;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public Model getModel(){
        return  mModel;
    }

    public  void setModel(Model model){
        mModel = model;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Model mModel;
    SaveFragment saveFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        saveFragment = (SaveFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SAVE_FRAGMENT");

        if (saveFragment != null) mModel = saveFragment.getModel();
         else {mModel = new Model();
               saveFragment = new SaveFragment();
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .add(saveFragment, "SAVE_FRAGMENT")
                                   .commit();
         }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        saveFragment.setModel(mModel);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот метод сам везде использую активно (нашел не через лекции, а по документации). Но не повторяйте мои ошибки: Никогда не используйте UI и не храните Viewы в этом фрагменте! Иначе утечка памяти по вашей вине будет вам обеспечена. Данные фрагменты ТОЛЬКО для хранения данных.

Comment: Это абсолютно правильный метод, не хак:) Вроде бы его даже сами гуглы рекомендуют:)

Comment: @Rishka Да вот собственно оффициальный пример - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: Ну да, лекции эти тоже не без участия гугл. Я к тому про хак, что это все же не явный инструмент, как тот же `SaveInstanceState`, а альтернативное использование некоторых свойств, которые изначально задумывались не именно для этого. Забавно, что я написал почти то же самое, что и в примере гугл - в лекциях несколько другая схема, без сеттера :)

Answer (score 1):

Я использую для тех же целей объект `Application`, аналогично ответу @pavlofff

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private  Model mModel;

    public Model getModel(){
        return  mModel;
    }

    public  void setModel(Model model){
        mModel = model;
    }
}
```

Также его нужно указать в AndroidManifest.xml, в  теге application:

```
android:name=”.MyApp”>
```

В activity или сервисе использовать так:

```
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
app.setModel();
```